# Javascript only executing Deferred2, not also deferred

Tags: javascript, arcgis, deferred

What I want is, I want to open an info window where I use the values from 2 different `IdentifyTask`s:

Here's my code:

```
dojo.connect(map, "onClick", executeIdentifyTask);

identifyTask = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("https://server.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/POI_Data/MapServer");

identifyTask2 = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("https://server.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ProRail_Data/MapServer");

identifyParams = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
identifyParams.tolerance = 15;
identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
identifyParams.layerIds = [0];
identifyParams.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
identifyParams.width = map.width;
identifyParams.height = map.height;

identifyParams2 = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
identifyParams2.tolerance = 10;
identifyParams2.returnGeometry = true;
identifyParams.layerIds = [23, 26, 31, 33];
identifyParams2.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
identifyParams2.width = map.width;
identifyParams2.height = map.height;

function executeIdentifyTask(evt) {

    identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
    identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
    var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);
    identifyParams2.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
    identifyParams2.mapExtent = map.extent;

    var deferred2 = identifyTask2.execute(identifyParams2);

    deferred.addCallback(function (response) {
        // response is an array of identify result objects    
        // Let's return an array of features.
        return dojo.map(response, function (result) {
            var feature = result.feature;
            feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
            if (result.layerName === 'Spoortoegang') {
                console.log(feature.attributes.PARCELID);
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("ToegangsNummer ${ToegangsNr}", "Toegangsnummer ${ToegangsNr} <br/> Baanvak: ${Baanvak},  <br/> Geocode: ${Geocode},  <br/> Kilometer: ${Kilometrering}");
                feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
                alert("Spoortoegang");
            }
            else if (result.layerName === 'sein') {
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "Parcel ID: ${NUMMER}");
                feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
            }
            return feature;
        });
    });

    deferred2.addCallback(function (response) {
        // response is an array of identify result objects    
        // Let's return an array of features.
        return dojo.map(response, function (result) {
            var feature = result.feature;
            feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
            if (result.layerName === 'Wissels') {
                console.log(feature.attributes.PARCELID);
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("Wissel", "Toegangsnummer ${ToegangsNr} <br/> Baanvak: ${Baanvak},  <br/> Geocode: ${Geocode},  <br/> Kilometer: ${Kilometrering}");
                feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
                alert("Wissels");

            }
            else if (result.layerName === 'sein') {
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "Sein Nummer: ${NUMMER}");
                feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
                alert("sein");
            }
            else if (result.layerName === 'Sporen') {
                console.log(feature.attributes.PARCELID);
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("Wissel", "Toegangsnummer ${ToegangsNr} <br/> Baanvak: ${Baanvak},  <br/> Geocode: ${Geocode},  <br/> Kilometer: ${Kilometrering}");
                feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
                alert("Sporen");
            }
            else if (result.layerName === 'bovenleidingpaal') {
                console.log(feature.attributes.PARCELID);
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("Wissel", "Toegangsnummer ${ToegangsNr} <br/> Baanvak: ${Baanvak},  <br/> Geocode: ${Geocode},  <br/> Kilometer: ${Kilometrering}");
                feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
                alert("bovenleidingspaal");
            }

            return feature;
        });
    });


    // InfoWindow expects an array of features from each deferred
    // object that you pass. If the response from the task execution 
    // above is not an array of features, then you need to add a callback
    // like the one above to post-process the response and return an
    // array of features.
    map.infoWindow.resize(195, 75);
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);

    map.infoWindow.resize(195, 75);
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred2]);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
}
```

I only get the alerts and `infowindow` content from the `deferred2`, not anything of `deferred`

Comment: What's your `result.layerName`? Try alerting before `if (result.layerName === 'Spoortoegang') {` in `deferred`

Comment: You're not getting the question right. I am getting that alert. Only not from deferred.. So i get the alert from Wissels.. The result.layername gets if LayerId [23, 26, 31, 33]; any of them is 'Wissels'.. Only i dont get the LayerID[0]; from deferred. so i'm not getting resylt.layerName==='Spoortoegang'. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: I mixed the 2 deferred's up, yea. I think you're not getting into any of the `if`'s in `deferred`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the code in `deferred2`:

```
deferred2.addCallback(function (response) {
    // response is an array of identify result objects    
    // Let's return an array of features.
    return dojo.map(response, function (result) {
        var feature = result.feature;
        feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
        var template;
        switch(result.layerName){
            case 'Wissels':
            case 'Sporen':
            case 'bovenleidingpaal':
                template = new esri.InfoTemplate("Wissel", "Toegangsnummer ${ToegangsNr} <br/> Baanvak: ${Baanvak},  <br/> Geocode: ${Geocode},  <br/> Kilometer: ${Kilometrering}");
            break;
            case 'sein':
                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "Sein Nummer: ${NUMMER}");
            break;
        }
        console.log(feature.attributes.PARCELID);
        feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        alert(result.layerName);

        return feature;
    });
});
```

This should work the same.

Comment: I see your point from my code yes, but i want different popups for Wissels, i just copied the values from Spoortoegang, because i wanted to see what it does, after that i want to change the values.. But do you have any idea how to fix it that the deferred.addCallback is called, not only deferred2....

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, yea. Make it work, then make it return the right values, right?
From what I can see, both your `deferred` functions are identical, aside from the `if-else` block having different requirements. Did you try `alert`ing inside `deferred`, before the `if`-block? I think the `if`'s conditions aren't returning `true`

Comment: Alert isnt called before the if, nor after the if

Comment: Any idea how to implement this example in my code? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/how-to-identify-layers-from-multiple-arcgis-server-instances

Comment: I just noticed `identifyParams.layerIds = [23, 26, 31, 33];`, shouldn't that be `identifyParams2.layerIds = [23, 26, 31, 33];` ? I'm not that familiar with ArcGIS, so I'm afraid not.

Comment: I'm just making wild guesses, now, but it might be that `map.infoWindow.resize(195, 75);` is resetting the infoWindow. I'm not familiar with `map.infoWindow`, though.

Comment: No i just want to put in the infowindow the 2 values. Deferred and deferred2. is that possible?

Comment: Oh already fixed it. Thanks for your help. I will accept this as answer. You have no idea how much that helped me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20155/discussion-between-cerbrus-and-babboe)